# Proguard shrinking behavior - 2nd level methods

Tags: android, proguard

Sorry if this is too basic - I'm struggling to find Proguard documentation I can understand.

My understanding of how Proguard shrinks Android applications is by looking for unused (uncalled?) methods and eliminating them from the build.  So if I have a method buynewCoke() that is never called anywhere else in the code, it will be removed.

However, what if there exists a method, say visitStoreAfterMidnight() that calls buyNewCoke().  And visitStoreAfterMidnight itself is never called.  Does Proguard still remove both of these methods? Or does it keep buyNewCoke() because it is refrenced by something?

That is, if A calls B and nothing calls A, how does Proguard behave?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both `visitStoreAfterMidnight()` and `buyNewCoke()` would be removed.

Actually it works similar to Garbage Collection, it starts from things that it needs to keep and check what they used and keep only these.

**Edit:**

official reference:
http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/introduction.html

> **Entry points**
>
> In order to determine which code has to be preserved and which code
>   can be discarded or obfuscated, you have to specify one or more entry
>   points to your code. These entry points are typically classes with
>   main methods, applets, midlets, activities, etc.
>
> In the **shrinking** step, ProGuard starts from these seeds and
>   recursively determines which classes and class members are used. All
>   other classes and class members are discarded.